# Cannot click on next button by using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web, web-crawler

I am trying to use Selenium to get the all the reviews of this link. However, my code always returns errors which I cannot click on the next button to see review in the next page.
I have tried some by using CSS_SELECTOR and XPATH but still not working.

I want to click on this button (in blue circle):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRpnY.png)

I also tried to use the Network from request but didnt find anything.
Could someone can look and see what I can do. Thank you very much.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
link = "https://www.conforama.fr/chambre-literie/textile-literie/couette/couette-240x220-cm-2-oreillers-60x60-cm-kit-couette-oreiller/p/473785#productInformations"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Desktop\python_export\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(link)
time.sleep(3)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "bv_main_container_row_flex"))).click()
time.sleep(1)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "bv_main_container_row_flex"))).click()
time.sleep(2)


try:
    next_page = "button.bv-content-btn.bv-content-btn-pages.bv-content-btn-pages-last.bv-focusable.bv-content-btn-pages-active"
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, next_page))).click()
    print("Working at the first try")
except:
    print("Not working at the first try")
    try:
        next_page = "li.bv-content-pagination-buttons-item.bv-content-pagination-buttons-item-next"
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, next_page))).click()
        print("Working at the second try")
    except:
        print("Not working at the second try")
        try:
            next_page = """//*[@id="BVRRContainer"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/ul/li[2]/button"""
            WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, next_page))).click()
            print("Working at the third try")
        except:
            print("Not working at the third try")
```

Comment: At which line are you stuck?

Comment: Hi. I am trying to click the next button by using different options. you can see I tried 3 try and except to see if which one is working. But not work at all

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the button which you are trying to click.

Comment: I have updated yet.

Comment: Possibly due to regional restrictions the _Next Page_ arrow element doesn't shows up at all in my system.

Comment: I have solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept the `cookie` first. To click on the cookie button use below code and then try to click `next` button using your second try code.

```
#Accept cookie
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#_evidon-accept-button"))).click()

try:
   next_page = "li.bv-content-pagination-buttons-item.bv-content-pagination-buttons-item-next"
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, next_page))).click()
   print("Working at the first try")
except:
    print("Not working at the first try")
```